# How detect in JQuery error load image?

Tags: jquery

How detect no load image in JQuery? And show instead of ([link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgDPI.png) show div id="error"

```
<img src="img.pl/ax.png" />
<img src="q.pl/ph.png"/>
<div id="error" style="">
  <div id="icoka"><i class="image icon"></i></div>
  <div id="content-text-error">Sorry, image not found : (</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could simply use the `onerror` attribute of `img` element

`<img src="noimage123.jpg" onerror="document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'block'"/>`

Check out the example: https://jsfiddle.net/s3du7jao/

### Edit 1 -

Added jQuery example `$("img").on("error", function(){...});`

https://jsfiddle.net/s3du7jao/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can register an `error` event listener with jQuery and do any action you want if the image can't get loaded.

```js
$("img").on("error", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#error").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="img.jpg" />
<div id="error" style="display: none;">Sorry, image not found :(</div>
```

Comment: Or `$("img").error(function(){ ... });` found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_error.asp Or for a dynamically added image: `$('body').on('error', 'img', function(e) { ... });`